# Showing result of Ping.SendAsync in label text

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm trying to create a simple GUI implementation of the ping program. I have a form which is just a text box `textBox1` where users enter the IP as a string, press a button `Ping`, and the result of the ping is displayed in a label `label1`. For some reason the text wont show up when I run the program.

Code partially taken from [Ping.SEndAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144961%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net;

namespace pinger
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string address;
        private string response;
        private PingReply reply;
        //public string response;

        private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            if (e.Error != null)
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            reply = e.Reply;
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();

            if (reply == null)
                return;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            address = IPtextbox.Text;
        }

        private void Ping_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            Ping pingSender = new Ping(); //creates a new 'pingSender' Ping object

            pingSender.PingCompleted += 
                new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            int timeout = 1000;
            pingSender.SendAsync(address, timeout, buffer, waiter);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "the ping was: " + reply.Status.ToString();
            Show();
            Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no text setting part in label in `ping_click`

Comment: Carefully reading whole sample on MSDN (instead of just using half) and reading through some other questions about SendAsync like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748245/how-to-use-ping-sendasync-working-with-datagridview would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you label only changes it's text when you click on it. `label1_Click` event is raised.

`PingCompleted` event to get information about the completion status and data collected by a call to the `SendAsync` methods. In it you can change your label text with the result of the ping.

Add all the code inside `label1_Click` to `PingCompletedCallback` method as follows;

```
private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled || e.Error != null)
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();

        reply = e.Reply;            

        if (reply == null)
            return;

        //Change the label here
        label1.Text = "the ping was: " + reply.Status.ToString();
        Show();
        Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: I actually went back to the MSDN article on ping and read the Ping.SendAsync method article which explains it. The Ping.SendAsync method triggers PingCompletedCallback when it completes. label1.text has to be there because that is the part of the code that runs next.

Comment: @AaronHensonWilson You're right. I'm about to add it to my answer.